# Unable to ssh using ed22519, although both client and server support it

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ubuntu-22.04

client & server OS/Version: Ubuntu 22.04.1

Logged in to the box via password, added my id_ed25519.pub to the user's authorized_keys. however it seems the server is refusing to accept the key.

Debugging ssh -v (client):

```
debug1: Skipping ssh-ed25519 key /home/x/.ssh/id_ed25519 - corresponding algo not in PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms
```

sshd -T output(server):

```
pubkeyacceptedalgorithms ...,ssh-ed25519,...
```

ssh -Q key (client):

```
...
ssh-ed25519
...
```

I specifically added `PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-ed25519` and `PubkeyAuthentication yes` to sshd_config and did a `systemctl restart sshd` however this had no effect whatsoever.

What might be causing the failure to use this key, even though both client and server should accept it?

Comment: **The problem is not the server.** Somehow you have ssh-ed25519 disabled on your _client_. Check client's ~/.ssh/config and /etc/ssh/ssh_config (not sshd) if any, or just run with `-oPubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms=ssh-ed25519` (although that's clumsy). (`ssh -Q` tells you what is _implemented in the code_ not what is configured as enabled.)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 `-oPubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms=ssh-ed25519` worked. So I had copied my config from another person. and they had set `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes ssh-rsa` without the + for whatever reason. Could you please make your comment an answer, so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @dave_thompson_085 's comment, the issue was with a misconfiguration of the client:

`PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes ssh-rsa` was preventing it from using ed25519

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this configuration from [mozilla security](https://infosec.mozilla.org/guidelines/openssh)

```
# Supported HostKey algorithms by order of preference.
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key

KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256

Ciphers chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr

MACs hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,umac-128@openssh.com

# Password based logins are disabled - only public key based logins are allowed.
AuthenticationMethods publickey

# LogLevel VERBOSE logs user's key fingerprint on login. Needed to have a clear audit track of which key was using to log in.
LogLevel VERBOSE

# Log sftp level file access (read/write/etc.) that would not be easily logged otherwise.
Subsystem sftp  /usr/lib/ssh/sftp-server -f AUTHPRIV -l INFO

# Root login is not allowed for auditing reasons. This is because it's difficult to track which process belongs to which root user:
#
# On Linux, user sessions are tracking using a kernel-side session id, however, this session id is not recorded by OpenSSH.
# Additionally, only tools such as systemd and auditd record the process session id.
# On other OSes, the user session id is not necessarily recorded at all kernel-side.
# Using regular users in combination with /bin/su or /usr/bin/sudo ensure a clear audit track.
PermitRootLogin No
```

---

You might need to to generate host keys like this `/usr/bin/ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key -N ''`